# How to compile Scintilla with GCC on Windows?

Tags: gcc, compilation, scintilla

Can someone provide a simple and straightforward step-by-step guide on how to build the Scintilla text editor component (DLL) on Windows using gcc?

Comment: Thanks for posting. This site works best if you tell us what you've tried along with why it didn't work and/or the errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

1. write a *.bat file like this:

   ```
   PATH = C:\path\to\mingw\bin\ 
   mingw32-make.exe
   ```
2. save with the name you want (for instance : **build.bat**)
3. put this file in path\to\dir\code\scintilla\win32
4. double click on this file.

Building the current last version (3.6.2) I get an error in file PlatWin.cxx, (line 2749) and the compilation fails.
I tried to compile an older version (3.4.3), and all went well.

Sergio